# SQL: Select airport which can arrived only with stop

Tags: sql, database, select, subquery

I have the following data structure:

```
flightnumber| goal | start
------------+------+-------
 LH-100     | ATL  | FRA
 LH-102     | DXB  | FRA
 LH-103     | ORD  | FRA
 LH-104     | HND  | FRA
 LH-105     | LHR  | FRA
 LH-106     | LAX  | FRA
 LH-107     | HKG  | FRA
 LH-108     | CDG  | FRA
 LH-109     | DFW  | FRA
 LH-110     | IST  | FRA
 LH-200     | ATL  | LHR
 LH-201     | PEK  | LHR
 LH-202     | DXB  | LHR
 LH-203     | ORD  | LHR
 LH-204     | FRA  | LHR
```

How can I select airports that you can only arrive from airport 'FRA' with a stop and not directly?

The result should be:

```
LH-201     | PEK  | LHR
```

Because from PEK you can not arrive FRA directly, only with a stop.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that I need the SELECT statement for this case.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read the guidelines.